# Starred file using Drive API doesn't star in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

setStarred is true/false -- fileId is the id of the file being changed

```
var body = {'labels': { "starred": setStarred } };
            var request = gapi.client.request({
                "path": 'drive/v2/files/'+fileId,
                'method': 'PUT',
                'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'alt': 'json'}, 
                'headers': { 
                    'Authorization': TOKEN
                },
                'body': body
            });
            request.execute(function(resp) {

            });
```

In my extension, it shows the file being starred. The File object returned shows the labels.starred value as true -- but in Google Drive, it's not showing as starred.

Am I doing something wrong? The list of files I grab from Google Drive using the Drive API seems to be showing the value as changed, but on Drive itself, it is not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it does star it in Drive but sometimes it's just VERY delayed in updating the file in Google Drive.